# Custom "CODE" button in Froala

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

How to create custom button with mechanism like B (bold) but for Src (code).
I make this, but it's not full functional:

```
$("#elm1").editable({
  inlineMode: false, 
  minHeight: 300,
  buttons: ["src"],
  customButtons: {
    src: {
      title: "Source",
      icon: {
        type: "txt",
        value: "Src" 
      },
    callback: function (editor){
      if (editor.getSelection() == "") {
        editor.insertHTML("<code></code>");
      } else {
        editor.insertHTML("<code>"+editor.getSelection()+"</code>");
      }
    }
  }
}
});
```

Comment: There's a `}` missing in your code.

Comment: it's not a problem, just sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$("#elm1").editable('insertHTML', "<code>"+$("#elm1").editable('text')+"</code>");`.